# Debugging startup issues in a C Windows Service

Tags: c, debugging, windows-services

I'm trying to debug an issue that happens on service startup. Trying to attach while things are running is failing, windbg times out with an error about a link lock. I think that the error occurs before I have a chance to attach. A sleep might let me attach, but is there a more elegant solution?

I'd like to start up the debugger first thing as the service starts. C# has a [Debugger.Launch()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch.aspx#Y0) method to start a debugger at runtime. Is there an equivalent C call that can be used without .net? Something I could just drop in the start routine.

I can't call DebugBreak because at the time the service has started I'm not under a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

`Sleep` is certainly a viable approach. It's crude yet effective. Somewhat less crude is to use a good logging framework to output diagnostics. With a sufficiently capable logging framework this can be very effective.

Comment: It turns out that depending on where you are sleep doesn't work so well. If the service doesn't return quickly the manager will kill it. Still struggling for a good solution. MSDN has a note http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx about debugging services that entails using two services. Maybe I'll have to go there, I was hoping not to.

Comment: Put some logging in. Easy and effective.